# How to make sure async task method calls gets executed synchronously

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

Hi i have textbox which has text changed event. Everytime a character is inserted in textbox the text changed event is fired. The Text changed event calls a async Task method. Below is the my event and async Task method.

```
public Textbox_TextChangedEvent()
    {
        GetStocks(texboxText);
    }

public async Task GetStocks(string texboxText)
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        await Task.Run(() => { CreateCollection(texboxText); });
        IsBusy = false;
    }
```

**Question**
How can i make sure GetStocks method is called synchronously one after the other.

**Example**
Suppose user has input `Ted` as input text. Then i want the the async call to be completed one after other.
i.e it should call GetStocks in following order and also complete the task in following order itself.

1. GetStocks(T)
2. GetStocks(Te)
3. GetStocks(Ted)

Comment: How is the desired behavior different than the current behavior?

Comment: What framework are you using? Is this a desktop app or a web app?

Comment: aaah if you want to queue up work, use a queue to store the work to be done, and then process it in order

Comment: I am using .Net framework and WPF App.

Answer (score 0):

To solve problems like this, we have used an `AsyncLock` previous projects. The `AsyncLock` will wait until the previous lock was released.

The `AsyncLock` may seem a little bit complicated first, but i hope the provided usage examples will illustrate its behaviour.

```
public class AsyncLock
{
   private TaskCompletionSource<object> _lastSection;

   public AsyncLock()
   {
      _lastSection = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
      _lastSection.SetResult(null);
   }

   public class ReleaseLock : IDisposable
   {
      private readonly TaskCompletionSource<object> _tcs;

      public ReleaseLock(TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs)
      {
         _tcs = tcs;
      }

      public void Dispose()
      {
         _tcs.SetResult(null);
      }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Enters and locks a critical section as soon as the currently executing task has left the section.
   /// The critical section is locked until the returned <see cref="IDisposable"/> gets disposed.
   /// </summary>
   public Task<ReleaseLock> EnterAsync()
   {
      var newTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
      var toAwait = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _lastSection, newTcs);
      return toAwait.Task.ContinueWith((_) => new ReleaseLock(newTcs), TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
   }
}
```

You then can use `await AsyncLock.EnterAsync()` to wait until any previous lock was released. In the `EnterAsync` we queue the next `Task` after the current `Task` using `ContinueWith`. This means the `await AsyncLock.EnterAsync()` will be executed after the previous has finished.

```
using (await _lock.EnterAsync())
{
    // ...
}
```

Here is an usage example:

```
class Program
{
   private static readonly AsyncLock _lock = new AsyncLock();

   private static async Task Test(int i, Task toComplete)
   {
      using (await _lock.EnterAsync())
      {
         await toComplete;
         Console.WriteLine(i);
      }
   }

   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      var tcs1 = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
      var tcs2 = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

      Task.Run(async () =>
      {
         var t1 = Test(1, tcs1.Task); // start first task
         var t2 = Test(2, tcs2.Task); // start second task

         tcs2.SetResult(null); // finish second first
         tcs1.SetResult(null); // fiish last task

         await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2); // will print: 1 and then 2
      }).Wait();
   }
}
```

The `Test` method takes will first enter the `Async` lock, then await the task `toComplete` and then write to the console.

We start two `Test` tasks (**"1"**, and **"2"**) and complete the second `toComplete` first. Without the `AsyncLock` the previous example prints: **"2"**, **"1"**.  With the `AsyncLock` however the tasks are processed in the sequence they were started.

**REMARKS:** One last remark. This will achieve your processing order, but can be tricky sometimes. Using locks like this can easily lead to deadlocks which are hard to solve and harder to find in the first place. **Use Locks very carefully**.

**EDIT:** Here a usage example your your problem:

```
private readonly AsyncLock _lock = new AsyncLock();

public Textbox_TextChangedEvent()
{
    GetStocks(texboxText); // every call is now "queued" after the previous one
}

public async Task GetStocks(string texboxText)
{
    using(await _lock.EnterAsync())
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        await Task.Run(() => { CreateCollection(texboxText); });
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That `ContinueWith` inside `EnterAsync` is strange. Passing in `newTcs` as state, only to have it ignored by the delegate? That feels like an attempt at avoiding closing over a local variable that was abandoned mid-way. Reminded me of this `AsyncLock` version (except this one actually uses the state): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/12/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-6-asynclock/)

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy you are right. Got the code from an old Silverlight project, where this parameter was not optional. Will update the answer.

Answer (score -1):

An easy option, depending on the situation could be:

```
public async Task GetStocks(string texboxText)
{
    Task.Run(() => { 
       IsBusy = true;
       CreateCollection(texboxText); 
       IsBusy = false;

    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the above code did not work for me. Actually the issue i am facing here is.In the order mentioned in my question, three async call are made,1.GetStocks(T)
2.GetStocks(Te)
3.GetStocks(Ted). But the sequence in which i get the result back is 3,2,1. But i want the result to come back in following order 1,2,3